# How to find a point after rotation?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Initially the position of the shape was in (100, 100). I am rotating (say 30 degrees) the shape as shown in the image below. I have found the starting point of the rotated object. Is there a formula to find the point of the shape when the rotation was 0 degree? Any help?

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "position of the shape was in (100,100)"? What are these coordinates with respect to?

Comment: (100, 100) is the left top corner of the first rectangle.

Comment: And where is (0,0)?

Comment: And which point are you rotating about?

Comment: Rotating w.r.t the center of the rectangle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rotating any point $(x,y)$ on a plane about the origin by $\theta$ degrees (counter-clockwise) is given by 
$$
\left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
x' \\
y' \\ 
\end{array}
\right] 
= 
\left[ 
\begin{array}{cc}
\cos \theta  & -\sin \theta  \\ 
 \sin \theta & \cos \theta \\  
\end{array}
\right] 
\left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
x \\
y \\ 
\end{array}
\right],  
$$
where $(x',y')$ denotes your new position.

Comment: No problem! For more information on rotational matrices: http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=rotational+matrix&oq=rotational+matrix&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&gs_l=youtube.3..0.146.3160.0.3174.20.15.0.2.2.0.255.1914.4j6j3.14.0...0.0.bifGYUjQsg4